# Two PowerShell commands together?

Tags: command-line, automation, powershell

How can I execute two PowerShell commands such that I only send text to the prompt once and the second command executes only after the first command has executed successfully?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563600/can-i-get-to-work-in-powershell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917271/execute-process-conditionally-in-windows-powershell-e-g-the-and-operator

Comment: I suggest you share your code and tell us why it doesn't work as you'd like.  You may need one of the suggestions from @Bob's comment or we may be able to fiddle with your pipeline to get similar results.

Comment: I don't have anything to share, as I had no idea how to do it, and my search efforts failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[command1] ; if ($Lastexitcode -eq 0) { [command2] }
```

This executes command1 and then command2 if `$Lastexitcode` equals 0. If command1 produces an error, it should throw that error and stop executing anyway (if it is a powershell command - if not, it depends).

Is this what you were looking for?

Edit: The links in Bobs comment also deliver detailed solutions to your question.